# Pandas, str.extract is not working with my regex?

Tags: python, pandas

Hello I'm trying to extract a substring with str.extract() but it doesn't want to work...

My regex

```
regex=r'(An+.+,$)'
dataset['Sprint']=dataset['URL'].str.extract(regex)
```

And What I would like to extract in bold :

[id=5548,rapidViewId=2968,state=ACTIVE,name=**Anki Sprint 1.12 glu**,startDate=2020-03-09T09:21:24.412+01:00,endDate=2020-03-31T23:59:00.000+02:00,completeDate=,sequence=5548,goal=]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is how you define the regex, your regex expression means 'extract a string matching: a character "A", with 1 or more characters "n", with 1 or more of any character (except for line terminators), a character "," and at the end of a line'. If you think about it, you cannot match this description in you example because you don't have a comma at the end of the line. You can try your regex expressions using this useful [website](https://regex101.com/), which gives you a good explanation of your regex expression.

Solving the problem, you can do

```py
regex=r'(An[a-zA-Z0-9\s]+.[a-zA-Z0-9\s]+),'
dataset['Sprint']=dataset['URL'].str.extract(regex)
```

or any other regex depending on how flexible you want your regex to be.

Comment: I'm new to regex, but you solved the problem by a very elegant way. I will take time to learn about regex, thank you :)

Answer (score 1):

Why not regex on name?

```
dataset['Sprint'] = df['URL'].str.extract("name=(.*?),")
```